# How to stop earth from wobbling?

Tags: animation

I'm working on an animation of the earth, and it is wobbling on the Z axis. I have it rotated on the X and Y axis as well, but there are no keyframes on them, even when I had keyframes on them the earth was still wobbling on the Z axis. How would I fix this?

Comment: It can be a number of reasons. E.g. have you parented it to something which moves? Or do you have some physics enables? If you shared your .blend, it would be a lot easier to discover the reason. You can upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then edit your question to include the link you'll be given once the upload is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your scene works, but if we are talking about regular rotation, the Earth should only be rotating on the Z-Axis.
Maybe you could ad a simple armature to it, with just the base and another bone parented to it that would control the Earth's rotation (sounds like the song The Spine from the Transistor OST...).